# Typedef Struct Understanding

Tags: c, struct, alias

I was hoping someone could tell me if my understanding is correct. This is part of the solution my prof gave us to our first assignment.

```
typedef struct alias{
  char *name;
  int numvalues;
  char *values[MAXARGS];
  struct alias *next;
} alias_node, *alias_nodeptr;

alias_nodeptr alias_dictionary;
```

So we are defining a struct alias, the name, numvalues and values is all familiar to me but the definition "struct alias *next;" We are defining an alias type in the alias struct, this is like the head pointer in a linked list. then at the end we are defining alias_node, *alias_nodeptr, this is the pointer we will be using to traverse the list, and the the very last line I am very confused about, I was hoping someone could explain that to me and correct me if I am misunderstanding anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After that typedef `struct alias` will be equivalent with `alias_node` and `struct alias *` will be equivalent with `alias_nodeptr`. You can use them interchangeably. You can't use `alias_node` or `alias_nodeptr` inside the struct itself because the typedef that binds that struct to a new name hasn't been evaluated yet.

It may be a bit confusing because the struct contains `numvalues` and `char *values[MAXARGS]`. It is a valid structure though: a linked list of nodes, each containing a name and a set of multiple (`numvalues`) values. There is no "list header" structure here, only the node. You can use linked lists without creating headers. You just need to remember the pointer to the first node in the list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your understanding of the `typedef` part is slightly incorrect. Your code snippet above is doing three things: It declares and defines a type named `struct alias`, it uses `typedef` to create type aliases to the `struct alias` and `struct alias *` types, and it declares a variable named `alias_dictionary`, whose type is one of those `typedef`d aliases.

First, you do this:

```
typedef struct alias{
  char *name;
  int numvalues;
  char *values[MAAXARGS];
  struct alias *next;
} alias_node, *alias_nodeptr;
```

Now, this is doing two things at once, so I'll restate it more simply:

```
struct alias {
  char *name;
  int numvalues;
  char *values[30];
  struct alias *next;
};
typedef struct alias alias_node, *alias_nodeptr;
```

This is the exact same thing, done as two separate steps.

First, we declare a `struct alias`, a compound type containing a pointer-to-char, an int, an array of pointer-to-char, and a pointer-to-struct.
Second, we define two type aliases, `alias_node` and `alias_nodeptr`, such that declaring `alias_node foo;` is equivalent to declaring `struct alias foo;`, and `alias_nodeptr bar` is equivalent to declaring `struct alias * bar;`.

And finally, Third.

```
alias_nodeptr alias_dictionary;
```

By now it should be fairly obvious what this is doing. You're declaring a variable named `alias_dictionary`, which is a pointer to `struct alias`.